# How do I turn off News notifications on my Apple Watch?

Tags: notifications, apple-watch, apple-news

Recently I started seeing News notifications on my Apple Watch:

[image]

I've confirmed that News is turned off in the Watch app on my iPhone under Notifications:

[image]

But I keep getting the notifications. I've tried turning News notifications on, and then off again. But I keep getting them.

Am I unaware of some other necessary setting that will disable these notifications?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, such an odd bug.

Answer (score 8):

Actually I was having the same problem and discovered why. In the News app itself there are some notification settings. Why it's so obscure and hard to find is unlike Apple, but it's there all the same.

Go to the News app and tap on the Favorites tab. At the very top you'll see three things: a bell gliph, a Favorites option (for sorting), and an Edit button. Tap on the bell gliph. It's for configuring the notifications.

[image: Favorites screen]

From there it's pretty self explanatory. You can turn on or off all notifications right there. It doesn't explicitly say Apple Watch notifications, but they are somehow intrinsically connected. I disabled all of them and it stopped harassing me on my watch.

They really should make the notification options separate for iOS and the watch. Seems dumb how I have to go in to a place that makes no sense just to turn off stuff.

Incidentally you can also stop the annoying barrage of default news sources here on the Favorites screen. Just hit Edit and remove them.

Comment: The  best option would've been to edit the existing answer to point out the additional steps.  As it is, there's two similar answers with slightly different info and this could confuse anyone else who has the same problem.

Comment: Please keep answers fact-based and focused. Different people will have different reasons for deselecting the default news sources, but the procedure to remove them is the same for everybody.

Comment: The procedure has changed, as the "Favorites" tab is now the "Following" tab.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Morpheus. I actually spent a lot of time on the phone with Apple support today with the same issue. Three different support specialists (one senior), and none of them had a solution.

My solution was to go into the news app and shut off all the alerts I really didn't care about. It's a work around for now until the next update fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

I have been having the same issue. It must be a bug. Please report it to Apple here:

http://www.apple.com/feedback/watch.html

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. (But thanks.)

Comment: Actually - this is a clear answer. Morpheus is saying it's purely a bug (and by implication - no settings will help anyone change this behavior). Whether this answer is right or wrong is debatable (please vote) but it's not a comment asking for clarification of the question, so calling for this to be a comment isn't how the site is set up.

Comment: It seems more like an answer now that it's been edited.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the News app just now.  Hope that stops the notifications.  Workaround will do for now until there is a solution.